# Mongodb schema for trello

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to make something similar to Trello.com.  There will be many boards, and each board can have many lists, and each lists can have many items.  The order of the lists and items can change often by the user, so I came up with something like this that would minimize queries. I just read some of the mongo documentation last night so I would appreciate any feedbacks and suggestions

Here is a list of boards:

```
 {
        boards: [
            {
                _id: 901292190
                name: 'board1'
            }
        ]
    }
```

Here is when you view a single board:

```
 {
        _id: 901292190
        name: 'board 1',
        lists: [
            {
                _id: 932092,
                name: 'todo',
                items: [
                    {
                        _id: 9320903,
                        name: 'go shopping',
                        priority: 1,
                        createdby: 'user1',
                        assignedto: 'user2'
                    },
                    {
                        _id: 3902901,
                        name: 'go to school',
                        priority: 2,
                        createdby: 'user1',
                        assignedto: 'user2'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'finished',
                items: [
                    {
                        _id: 91209,
                        name: 'programming',
                        priority: 1,
                        createdby: 'user1',
                        assignedto: 'user2'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: To get answers, you should ask a concrete question...

Comment: I am fairly certain trello team members have actually stated their schema on this site if you do a little searching, I know they take an active part here

Comment: I recommend you watch http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/schema-design-9. It gives concrete examples of schema design in MongoDB. Is there a more specific question you have?